# Conway's $1(0),000 challenge

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

### Background

This challenge is about [A004001](https://oeis.org/A004001), a.k.a. **Hofstadter-Conway $10000 sequence**:

$$
a_1 = a_2 = 1, \quad a_n = a_{a_{n-1}} + a_{n-a_{n-1}}
$$

which starts with

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, ...
```

[John Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway) proved the following property of the sequence:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{a_n}{n}}=\frac12
$$

After the proof, he offered $1(0),000 for the smallest \$k\$ such that all subsequent terms of \$a_j/j\$ after the \$k\$-th term are within 10% margin from the value \$1/2\$, i.e.

$$
\left|\frac{a_j}{j}-\frac12\right|<\frac1{20},\quad j > k
$$

To quote Sloane's comment on the OEIS page (which explains the title):

> John said afterwards that he meant to say $1000, but in fact he said $10,000. [...] The prize was claimed by Colin Mallows, who agreed not to cash the check.

Here are some graphs to get some feel of the sequence (copied from [this MathOverflow.SE answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/357297)):

[image]

Also check out [A004074](https://oeis.org/A004074), which lists the values of \$2a_n-n\$.

### Challenge

Given the amount of margin \$r\$, solve the generalized Conway's challenge: find the smallest \$k\$ which satisfies

$$
\left|\frac{a_j}{j}-\frac12\right|<\frac{r}{2},\quad j > k
$$

This can be also phrased as the largest \$k\$ that satisfies \$\left|\frac{a_k}{k}-\frac12\right|\ge\frac{r}{2}\$. You can assume \$0<r<1\$, so that the task is well-defined in both ways.

(The original challenge is \$r=0.1\$, and the answer by Colin Mallows is 1489, according to [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hofstadter-Conway10000-DollarSequence.html) (which agrees with my own implementation). The value of 3173375556 on the MO answer is probably the one for \$r=0.05\$.)

For simplicity, you may assume a few conjectured properties of the sequence:

- \$a_n = n/2\$ when \$n = 2^k, k \in \mathbb{N}\$.
- \$2a_n - n\$

  - is nonnegative everywhere,
  - is 0 when \$n = 2^k, k \in \mathbb{N}\$,
  - follows the [Blancmange curve-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve) pattern between the powers of two (as visible in the second figure above), and
  - when divided by \$n\$, has the maximum values between powers of two decreasing as \$n\$ increases (as visible in the first figure above).

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
r     | answer
------+-------
0.9   | 1
0.4   | 1
0.3   | 6
0.2   | 25
0.15  | 92
0.13  | 184
0.12  | 200
0.11  | 398
0.1   | 1489
0.09  | 3009
0.085 | 6112
0.08  | 22251
```

[Reference implementation in Python](https://tio.run/##lVLBboMwDL3zFZZ2KIHQkdJOGxv9EZRDtpo2Ek1ZoFqnrt/O4qRVu0k7DKFHYj8/vzh0n8NmZ4px7PEdKqhzDsK9Mmp2FjRoA1aZNcYFF7l/WBmBMlvhyK6k1pnj0mqqug7NKqYg5SWkgQCZ50sW3XVWm8EzRFlQZFB2jYPvC7oBXVU5YNsjxLPEZJrda/A@uCEnaPZbtGpAkmDyohdESHJOTX4ZF3zmPEOgzpJEc3AY61QwDlt1uJRTqrxkJOW0@SPHohU20O/a2NI0tPMvnqFV/YCHN8RV2Pf7V2WtW59FrvlUlNdNMk9pgh8b3aL3E@rYsrJO@6dqfR7H9XS3OvyGzCETjEZ6bq4lLCuwsvbX9U9vFoe9NTfqkf87LNmo8@kTh3w6JygIZgRi4dEHRIgIjwS5r8gfF@Ej3TnD9TSToy1fHk5fcAzTPU3YOH4D).

(A hint for termination check: A value of \$k\$ is the answer if \$\frac{2a_k}{k}-1\ge r\$ and \$\frac{2a_j}{j}-1< r\$ for \$k < j \le 4k\$.)

Comment: I thought this post is spam when I first read its title.

Comment: This would be a great fastest-code.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

Slow as hell.

```javascript
g=n=>n<3||g(n-g(--n))+g(g(n))
f=(r,n=1,m)=>(x=g(n)*2-n)|m?f(r,n+1,x<r*n?x&&m:o=n):o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcpBDoIwEIXhPafoisxACyLERMLAWQhCo6EzphjDgrtXWLgxcfn@7z36d78M/v58GZbbGIIlppabctsssLFgDCOmFvaFGE0EXjMV2iG1sNJRk/N@2Vw3HZQWem18wt0ax64WYqwlDMKLzGM2i4UJTtlVKUSV56qIfqn6T@WXLuED)

#### How?

We look for the highest \$n\$ such that:
$$2\cdot a(n)-n \ge r\cdot n$$

We stop when no greater value is found in a whole interval:

$$[2^k+1,2^{k+1}], k>0$$

whose upper bound is characterized by \$2\cdot a(n)-n=0\$.

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 94 bytes

A much faster version using a cache to prevent too many recursive calls.

```javascript
g=n=>g[n]=g[n]||n<3||g(n-g(--n))+g(g(n))
f=(r,n=1,m)=>(x=g(n)*2-n)|m?f(r,n+1,x<r*n?x&&m:o=n):o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/BCoMwDAbg@56iJ2nVqq06rFh9kLGDOC0bmg4dw0Pf3SnoDiu7BJIvJPyP@l1PzXh/vijoW7ssSoIs1QWucivGQBEbozBQhSkFQjyF146QUyfx6INk/kBkiWe5TV2@rpih6jbymD8XowvV7DhDriWQXC@Nhkn3bdBrhTscBQIhQlAYInb6peQ/xQedLeIH8dQylu4muG3x8S1LbOTH0Siyke0Yi8zGb4gkE8sH)

Comment: What does \$k\$ stand for here?

Comment: @petStorm Any positive integer.

Comment: @petStorm To be a bit more specific, we don't care about the value of \$k\$. We just need to know that we've reached the boundary of the Blancmange curve, which happens whenever \$n\$ is a power of \$2\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 40 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞oüŸvy¦R.ΔтS_λè₅N₁-₅+}·yαIy*@}Dˆ(i¯àDdiq
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimmy*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9vc2FiaWX//@KInm/DvMW4dnnCplIuzpTRglNfzrvDqOKChU7igoEt4oKFK33Ct3nOsUl5KkB9RMuGKGnCr8OgRGRpcf//MC4xMQ) (No test suite, because of the `q`.)

**Explanation:**

Inspired by [*@Arnauld*'s approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203724/52210), so I too look for the largest \$n\$ such that:
$$2\cdot a(n)-n \ge r\cdot n$$

And I also stop when no greater value is found in a whole interval:
$$\left(2^k,2^{k+1}\right],k>0$$

```python
∞                 # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 o                # Take each as 2 to the power: [2,4,8,...]
  ü               # For each overlapping pair:
   Ÿ              #  Create a list in that range:
                  #   [[2,3,4],[4,5,6,7,8],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],...]
vy                # Loop over each inner list in the range [a,b]:
  ¦               #  Remove the first value to make the range (a,b]
   R              #  Reverse it to [b,a)
  .Δ              #  Find the first value `y` in this list which is truthy for,
                  #  or -1 if none are found:
       λ          #   Create a recursive environment,
        è         #   to output the `y`'th value afterwards
    тS_           #   Start it at a(0)=0, a(1)=a(2)=1
                  #   (push 100 as list [1,0,0] and invert booleans to [0,1,1])
                  #    (implicitly push a(n-1))
         ₅        #    And use that for a(x): a(a(n-1))
         N₁-      #    Push n-a(n-1)
            ₅     #    And use that for a(x) as well: a(n-a(n-1))
             +    #    And add those together
       }·         #   After the recursive environment, double it: 2*a(y)
         yα       #   Take the absolute difference with `y`: |2*a(y)-y|
           Iy*    #   Push the input multiplied by `y`
              @   #   Check |2*a(y)-y| >= input*y
   }Dˆ            #  After the found_first, add a copy to the global_array
      (i          #  If this value was -1 (thus none were found):
        ¯         #   Push the global_array
         à        #   Pop and push its maximum
          D       #   Duplicate it
           di     #   Pop the copy, and if this maximum is NOT -1:
             q    #    Terminate the program
                  #    (after which this maximum is output implicitly as result)
```

NOTE: The `vy` cannot be `ε` or `ʒ` to act as a foreach with implicit `y`, because we'd need a `--no-lazy` flag in order to have a proper output, which isn't possible due to the lazy infinite recursive list.

Comment: `011S` => `тS_`

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks. I had the feeling that could be golfed, but didn't think about that..

Answer (score 3):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>110</s> <s>109</s> <s>108</s></sup> 105 bytes

```bash
a=(0 1 1)
v=1
m=1
for((n=3;c<2;n++)){
c=$[a[n]=v=a[v]+a[n-v],(2*v-n)*$2>=$1*n?m=n,0:c+!(n&n-1)]
}
echo $m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/NToQwFIX39ymOpGP4GRxaxsRxKK506wMQFqVlZBJpDY5oYnx2LExY9PtOm5Pc20Z9dpNWF5T4GNzboHoURfD8@hJMSoYZOHhEo@TU@3NyQxhamR91IY42SaLol7RklapsLUepqrFOfE7HehuKeExtFDNRSsZj@9RLu80edXIT2lub8qimP2p158D6yY8j0l3vDL6Sn3URou/u/N5iaJWBQkOAcR7whbO9nBBshMEOm72BLBGAKbBmKdzt1s@sb8bZdjqAZ7Sfkc8QM/i9p1d@lbiKXzUXDkt8WGrey@0f)

*3 bytes off due to the same improvements made by ceilingcat for my C answer.*

Input is a fraction, passed as arguments -- the numerator in the first argument, and the denominator in the second argument.  For example, to pass 0.13, the command would look like: `./program 13 100`

(Bash doesn't support floating-point numbers natively, but rational numbers are perfect for this challenge.)

The program runs quickly enough that it can get through all the OP's test cases in a single run at TIO, even though bash is a relatively slow interpreted language.

Output is on stdout.

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 178 bytes

```erlang
a(X)->case X>2 of true->a(a(X-1))+a(X-a(X-1));_->1end.
c(R)->c(R,1,0,0).
c(R,N,M,O)->case 2*a(N)-N>R*N of true->c(R,N+1,N,N+1);_->case N>O bsl 1of true->M;_->c(R,N+1,M,O)end end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3RCsIgFIbv9xReHjcdc3VTgW8wB7saRIQtC2G5cIse31RWuwjmhcr5vvP/yvbS3KkaO6ufk0uchBZT3slRoZaXaLihyb4U5RI8oQzjLLzz/3CmnClzzZMOmrAGDWGkIAWOEyJIRepvXJlKEJgK3qRiyY1axrzq7xgYZcFrdBl7xH5iFdlsh1jfi0K3e0ht4HjyPQnyRw/7t9WTgg6KfIcx8QPTAyb/dLtKN6u0XGjuPg)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>119</s> <s>116</s></sup> 113 bytes

```c
f(float r){int a[99999]={0,1,1},v=1,m=1,n=2,c=0;for(;c<2;c=2*v>=r*n+n?m=n,0:c+!(n&n-1))a[n]=v=a[v]+a[++n-v];v=m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5NasMwEIX3PsU0kCBFsiM5DTRVJz2I64VQotYQj4sa1IXx2V1JdOB78Jg3P67@dG5dPfP3yT4g8HmgB9junKvHWUkt9SIjajkmCFvpUBk/BWbcW2sctvt4wbAnQe8jklSvTjwx2lGtObcd9RjRdrEXthOC6tibiKNZ1nxmtAOxOA1XXgHAnAX@/zBVcb9fw/0GTAMi/DhLnm22fiNhF3iZyfUd0i4PqdMcPeAFttcPSpkgwbOUMzm4wOFQ7q2qOVeqeU4cE21Cn7Jkp4vVWRIqB9XLqWj1Bw)

*3 bytes off thanks to ceilingcat.*

*And now 3 more bytes off from ceilingcat.*

This is a port of my bash answer.  It's a function which accepts `r` as an argument (a float this time) and returns the desired result.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks -- bash arithmetic expressions are close enough to C that the same improvements worked on my bash answer too.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thank you.